# Bhyve : tap0 bridged network interface for ubuntu instance times out during startup

Tags: virtualization, freebsd

I'm trying to setup an ubuntu instance using iohyve under FreeNAS 9.10, the instance will boots up but timeout when trying to raise the network interface.

So far I've tried to double check the taplist being linked:

```
[@freenas] /nonexistent# iohyve taplist
Listing all network taps:
HelperDrive/iohyve/ubuntuserver16......tap0
```

That the tunnel is set to be up on open:

```
[@freenas] /nonexistent# sysctl net.link.tap.up_on_open
net.link.tap.up_on_open: 1
```

and my ifconfig setup:

```
[@freenas] /nonexistent# ifconfig bridge0
bridge0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    description: iohyve-bridge
    ether 02:XX:XX:XX:45:00
    nd6 options=9<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED>
    id 00:00:00:00:00:00 priority 32768 hellotime 2 fwddelay 15
    maxage 20 holdcnt 6 proto rstp maxaddr 2000 timeout 1200
    root id 00:00:00:00:00:00 priority 32768 ifcost 0 port 0
    member: tap0 flags=143<LEARNING,DISCOVER,AUTOEDGE,AUTOPTP>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 128 path cost 2000000

[@freenas] /nonexistent# ifconfig tap0
tap0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    description: iohyve-ubuntuserver16
    options=80000<LINKSTATE>
    ether 00:XX:XX:XX:01:00
    inet 0.0.0.0 netmask 0xff000000 broadcast 255.255.255.255 
    nd6 options=9<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED>
    media: Ethernet autoselect
    status: active
    Opened by PID 2710
```

When I start the ubuntu instance (via `iohyve start myUbuntuInstance`), I notice the following error during bootup:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
See 'systemctl status networking.service' for details.
```

running systemctl just reveals this:

```
ubuntuFreeNAS:~$ systemctl status networking.service | less
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Fri 2017-04-07 15:40:57 PDT; 19min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
 Main PID: 796 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

Apr 07 15:35:57 ubuntuFreeNAS systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Apr 07 15:35:57 ubuntuFreeNAS ifup[796]: /sbin/ifup: waiting for lock on /run/network/ifstate.enp0s3
Apr 07 15:40:57 ubuntuFreeNAS systemd[1]: networking.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Apr 07 15:40:57 ubuntuFreeNAS systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Apr 07 15:40:57 ubuntuFreeNAS systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 07 15:40:57 ubuntuFreeNAS systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

I'm a bit of a newbie on the virtual networking front - What other things can I look into to debug this?

Comment: Realized that part of the problem, if not the problem, is that bridge0 only contains one member (the virtual interface tap0) instead of also including the physical interface (e.g. igb0, ix0, or whatever ifconfig shows as the interface with the actual assigned ip)

Answer (score 0):

On my particular freeNAS setup, I had a `bridge1` interface (which already had my physical `ix1` interface as a member) in addition to the `bridge0` created by iohyve.

My solution was to ignore `bridge0` and add the `tap0` interface to `bridge1` instead by using `ifconfig bridge0 deletem tap0` then `ifconfig bridge1 addm tap0`.